# Why doesn't text editing stop after I click a button in Codename One

Tags: android, codenameone

I recently encountered an issue with the native android virtual keyboard in [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/).

My keyboard is still showing after I clicked the validation button that changes a `Container` (with some `TextField`) to another `Container`.

Why doesn't the editing stop after I click a button?

This question was migrated from [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/vE8NgTthS9k/Or72FFBZGwAJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual keyboard on iOS/Android fold when we show a new `Form` but don't necessarily fold when we press a button.

You can explicitly stop editing using [TextField.stopEditing()](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/TextArea.html#stopEditing--) or [Display.stopEditing(Component)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#stopEditing-com.codename1.ui.Component-).